# reactnavigation hiding statusbar leaves space above header

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I use reactnavigation and I am hiding the statusbar at the top, but it leaves an empty space above the header.

I already tried paddingTop or marginTop, but none work.

This is how I hide the statusbar.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Tabs, Drawer } from './config/router';

const App = () => (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <Drawer />
    </View>
);

export default App;
```

Any idea would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Try by adding `<StatusBar hidden/>` in `render` method of your main screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How to Fix it**

I add the following to the index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Tabs, Drawer } from './config/router';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';

SafeAreaView.setStatusBarHeight(0);

const App = () => (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <Drawer />
    </View>
);

export default App;
```

Basically added the **SafeAreaView** part.

Hope this is helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Try the static function [Status Bar](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#sethidden). You might need to convert the component to a React Component/Pure Component. Try it with and without converting it.

```js
componentDidMount(){
 StatusBar.setHidden(true,true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried it but still have the same issue. This is btw how it looks, the light-blue highlighted is the header and you can see the space above it. https://ibb.co/iFtoqo

Comment: That looks like the header itself and not the status bar.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I am unable to remove the space, already tried marginTop from the navigation, but no luck

Comment: Using the status bar can you set a color to the background at least ? Can you manipulate it in any way?

Comment: Colouring of the status bar is not an issue. I think I will keep the statusbar for now, until there is a fix for it.